# Strategy for cascading installation of Maven projects depending on a particular project

Tags: maven

I have to deal with a Maven project A which is referenced by many other Maven projects. I would like to ensure that installing project A (mvn install) induces the installation of projects that depends on project A.
I'd like to know what's the best strategy for that? Is using a plugin that installs the projects referencing project A a good practice?

Thanks for your answers.

PS: Since project A is a JAR Maven project, it is not possible to consider it as a multi-modules project.

Comment: Do you know exactly which other projects use project A? And is it absolutely necessary that they are immediately rebuilt to take account of changes?

Comment: Yes, I know exactly which other projects use project A, and yes it is necessary to rebuild immediatly other projects because it's tedious to manually rebuild 20 projects when project A is rebuilt.

Comment: precision: all projets share the same version name.

Answer (score 2):

As you're aware of all the rebuilds required, and it's a pain to do this manually. I'd suggest you do the following:

- Install Jenkins or an other continuous integration tool
- Have a build job to build & deploy (to a tool like Nexus*) Project A every time a change is made to the source control repository for that project
- Have a build job for each subsequent project, which will take in the newly-deployed version of Project A, and deploy the built artefacts to Nexus
- Nexus is a Maven repository manager.

Comment: Thank for very much your answer. The inconvenient of such a solution is it forces me to check out the other projects from Nexus each time I install my project A. And I want to apply my solution in a local environment, and possibly without being aware of the dependencies toward my project A.

Comment: Well, the checkout from Source Control can be automatic with Jenkins. I don't know of anything you can do if you're not aware of a project with Project A as a dependency - this is more of an issue for the developers of that project.

Comment: Isnt'it possible to take advantage of Maven Reactor Plugin? It allows to rebuild all projects that depends on a particular projet. Unfortunately, it can only be used in multi-modules projects